# My 2004 Chevy trailblazer won't accelerate or just got maybe 5-10

Tags: chevrolet, transmission, maintenance, trailblazer

I'm trying to figure out why my truck driver won't move. If I leave it off and turn it on it goes maybe 5-10 mph and then just completely stops moving and you can just hear it revving. Can someone help me come up with possible answers, I'm thinking I have a clog but not sure.

Comment: Which model of TB is this (plain TB or TBSS)? Have you checked your transmission fluid? Is there enough in it? What color is it? How does it smell?

Comment: I have the plain TB. I have enough transmission fluid, its like blackish red, you can kind of see the red if it runs down something white,an has like a burnt rubber kind of smell to it

Comment: OP, looks like it's been a few months since you posted...what was the outcome?

Answer (score 1):

You can try and get the transmission flushed and might get a few more thousand miles out of it, but from the sounds of it, your tranny is toast. It will either need a rebuild or a swapped out for a new/rebuilt one.

What is happening is the soft parts of the transmission (bands/clutches) are worn out. They no longer have any grip to give you the momentum. You trying to drive it is only causing more damage. If you do it too much, you'll cause hard parts to fail, which will make the repair bill that much more expensive. Get it towed to a repair shop and have them diagnose/repair the transmission. It's about your safest bet at this point.